# In DashCode, how to access the dataArray from an onClick handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dashcode

I have a list that is automatically populated from an XML DataSource using bindings.

Each XML record contains a title, a description and a URL

Each UI row contains a title and a description.

When `onclick` is called on the title, I would like to call the openURL with the URL specified in the DataSource.

Is it possible to identify the current selection and navigate in the datamodel from the `onclickHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Dashcode project I'm working on right now I have a datasource that includes a URL to the product on Amazon.com. I haven't done this from the list view, but from my detail view I created a link to the Amazon page for the currently displayed product.

On the detail layout the URL field is transformed to be:

"Click here to purchase the product on Amazon.com."

And the word here is a standard html link.

I used a Value Transformer to do this. In my data source the URL field contains a fully qualified URL to the product on Amazon.com. So where you see "value" in the code below Dashcode is replacing that with a URL in the HTML code that is then included in the page.

```
myBuildAmazon = Class.create(DC.ValueTransformer,{
    transformedValue: function(value){
        // Insert Code Here
        value="Click <a href="+value+" target='_blank' >here</a>  to purchase the product on Amazon.com.";
        return value;
    }
});
```

One important thing is that when you bind the datasource to the field select HTML from the popup menu that comes up rather than Text.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, that works, but doing so you generate a new link in the page, you are not using the onClick event of the button itself.